# spark write timestamp as long in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

im reading data from jdbc source and writing it directly into elastic search index.
when I queried the data in ES I saw that all timestamp fields in my dataframe transformed to long

see my code below

```
 val appName="ExractToolEngine"
 val master = "local[2]"
 val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
 conf.set("es.write.operation", "index")
 conf.set("es.mapping.id", "user_id")
 conf.set("index.mapper.dynamic", "true")
 conf.set("es.mapping.rich.date", "true")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val srcData = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").
      options(Map("driver"->"com.jdbc.Driver",
      "url" -> "jdbc...",
      "dbtable"-> "tbl",
      "partitionColumn"-> "user_id",
      "lowerBound"-> "1",
      "upperBound"-> "1000000",
      "numPartitions"-> "50"
      )
).load()
    srcData.filter("user_id>=1 and user_id<=1000000").saveToEs("test_users/sm_1")
```

}

when I run `srcData.printSchema()`

I get:

```
|-- dwh_insert_ts: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- dwh_update_ts: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

when I query the index mapping  on http://localhost:9200/test_users/_mapping/sm_1

I see

```
"properties": {
"dwh_insert_ts": {
"type": "long"
},
"dwh_update_ts": {
"type": "long"
},
```

is there a away to force elasticsearch to stay with timestamp and do the conversion?

Comment: But timestamps *are* long aren't they ?

Comment: spark timestamp represent datetime object which I can apply datetime function without the need to convert it from long (similar to other RDBMS like mysql and postgres)

Answer (score 0):

There're several date formats you can use
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html

Comment: I need to predefined all my timestamp field in advance?
my schema can change and I don't want to have to predefine all my fields
is there away around it ?

Comment: You don't need to define all the fields, define only date fields, also you can use dynamic mapping if you have specific name pattern in date fields' names like "created_date","updated_date".

Comment: according to [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html) I can't do dynamic mapping to timestamp fileds

Comment: It's another "dynamic" mapping, check this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following [ES doc page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html).

Also it looks to me that your configuration is wrong and useless:

```
conf.set("es.mapping.rich.date", "true")
```

The correct name is defined in [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/mapping.html#mapping-date):

```
es.mapping.date.rich
```

Since it's defaulted to `true` you probably don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem and i have solved it. 
transform the timestamp to the utc format, for example "2020-05-11T14:44:24.000+08:00" and this is a Asia/Shanghai time. then write it to es, es will map it as date type.